# Job ends with error "WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... failed"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I am trying to set up a GitLab ce server running in docker, on my local Windows machine for the moment. Trying to configure GitLab CI, I am facing an issue when uploading the artifact at the end of the job:

WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... failed  id=245 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=i3yfe7rf

[image: Job failure in GitLab]

Before showing more logs, this is my setup. I am using different containers

- one for running GitLab
- one for running the CI runners (gitlab-runner)
- one for running a container registry
- one recently added container to store artifacts on a local s3 server (minio)

This is the config.toml file for the only registered runner. Note that this version uses a local s3 server, but the same happens with local cache.

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Docker Runner"
  url = "http://192.168.1.18:6180/"
  token = "JHubtvs8kFaQjJNC6r6Z"
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://192.168.1.18:6180/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "mycustom-s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "192.168.1.18:9115"
      AccessKey = "XXXXXX"
      SecretKey = "XXXXXX"
      BucketName = "runner"
      Insecure = true
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:19.03.1"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

This is my CI YAML file: I've taken this example from a youtube video. The same happens for all projects in GitLab.

```
image: "ruby:latest"

cache:
  paths:
    - output

before_script:
  - bundle install --path vendor  # Install dependencies into ./vendor/ruby

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker,ruby
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - output/
    expire_in: 5 days   
  script:
    - echo "In the build stage"
    - mkdir -p output
    - echo date > output/$(date +%s).txt
    - ls -l output
    - ls -l vendor
```

Running the job ends with the above mentioned error.

More errors can be seen in the log files:

- In exceptions_json.log:

{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2020-12-16T11:24:11.865Z","correlation_id":"ZxQ4vVdD1J1","tags.correlation_id":"ZxQ4vVdD1J1","tags.locale":"en","exception.class":**"Errno::ENOENT","exception.message":"No such file or directory @ apply2files - /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/work/1608117851-2655-0006-1409/artifacts.zip"**...

- In Production.log

  Started POST "/api/v4/jobs/245/artifacts/authorize?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=5+days" for 172.17.0.1 at 2020-12-16 11:24:07 +0000
  Started POST "/api/v4/jobs/245/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=5+days" for 172.17.0.1 at 2020-12-16 11:24:07 +0000
  Processing by Gitlab::RequestForgeryProtection::Controller#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"file.remote_url"=>"", "file.size"=>"389", "file.sha1"=>"da6c0be0e7a3a4791035bc9f851439dcb0e94135", "file.sha256"=>"6539358258571174fb3bed6ab68db78705efdd9ed4b7c423bab0b19eb9aea531", "file.path"=>"/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/uploads/artifacts.zip609500792", "file.remote_id"=>"", "file.name"=>"artifacts.zip", "file.md5"=>"d432c9507b8879dfad13342c6b60f73b", "file.sha512"=>"5ea4e5b6bcbbffb2d3f81e8c05ede92b630b6033ea3f09dc61a4a4bbc7919088cf4a1eab46cd54e9e994b35908065412779e77caf2612341fed3c36449947bdd", "file.gitlab-workhorse-upload"=>"...", "metadata.name"=>"metadata.gz", "metadata.path"=>"/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/uploads/metadata.gz123385207", "metadata.remote_url"=>"", "metadata.sha256"=>"93d549eb28b503108a4e9da0cb08cac02cd70041aedcbef418aa5c969d1a0d1e", "metadata.size"=>"175", "metadata.remote_id"=>"", "metadata.sha512"=>"3c7ff2a2a992695c2082c37340be7caa2955e9ba4ff50015c787f790146da1ac7f6884685797db1bc59eb8045bab1fac2fc1300114542059cddcec2593ea5934", "metadata.md5"=>"c7b52bc3b9b2d7dbf780aa919917b562", "metadata.sha1"=>"c71ab07f5bdf21d8d3b5a6507a0747167d4a80de", "metadata.gitlab-workhorse-upload"=>"...", "file"=>#<UploadedFile:0x00007fb805291cf0 @tempfile=#File:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/uploads/artifacts.zip609500792, @size=389, @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="artifacts.zip", @sha256="6539358258571174fb3bed6ab68db78705efdd9ed4b7c423bab0b19eb9aea531", @remote_id="">, "artifact_format"=>"zip", "artifact_type"=>"archive", "expire_in"=>"5 days", "metadata"=>#<UploadedFile:0x00007fb804cdcfa8 @tempfile=#File:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/uploads/metadata.gz123385207, @size=175, @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="metadata.gz", @sha256="93d549eb28b503108a4e9da0cb08cac02cd70041aedcbef418aa5c969d1a0d1e", @remote_id="">}
  **Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.**
  This CSRF token verification failure is handled internally by `GitLab::RequestForgeryProtection`
  Unlike the logs may suggest, this does not result in an actual 422 response to the user
  For API requests, the only effect is that `current_user` will be `nil` for the duration of the request
  Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 241)

  **Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ apply2files - /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/work/1608117848-2659-0005-4872/artifacts.zip)**:
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:320:in `chmod'...

I've been spending my last 3 days searching the root of this, and despite having read many articles (here or on GitLab support site), I can't get this resolved.

The error suggests this is an issue with file /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/work/1608117848-2659-0005-4872/artifacts.zip.
Definitely, directory /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/work/ exists.
But sub-directory 1608117848-2659-0005-4872 doesn't.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: same here, resetting runner tokens did not help (as they suggest in the gitlab issues)

Comment: @bokabraq could you test the same configuration on a Linux machine?

Comment: @goroncy, sorry I don't have a Lunix machine to test this on. Using docker volumes instead of bind mounts did the trick on my side.

Comment: @cguedel I lost myself in many issues on GitLab support site. It was never exactly the same issue I had though. On the bright side, I learned a lot of stuff reading all this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning and finally solved it for me.

I was using bind-mounts for the data/config/log volumes in the gitlab container, which apparently cause a problem when uploading the artifacts.

I now switched to using docker volumes and now artifact upload works.

Comment: I'm not using bind mounts. Just volumes. And I still have the same exact problem. I think that the root cause is that the runner is not able to upload the artifact zip to the CI. Just a guess unfortunately. Logs tell nothing.

Comment: Switching from bind mounts to docker volume worked! Thanks so much for suggesting this! Definitely the API endpoint used to upload the artifact to GitLab container doesn't like having Windows folders as bind mounts... I regret I did not test this earlier! Although, having bind mounts is so useful to browse through config files in Notepad++. I can now move forward in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Guys. I'm stupid. I was using a version of docker-compose.yml where I in fact used bind mounts. Changed it to volumes. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you show me what you mean by switching to volumes?
My Config looks like this: 
```
gitlab-shared-runner:
    restart: always
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    container_name: gitlab-shared-runner
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
```

Comment: @dependent you can define volumes in your docker-compose file and mount it to your container. This is similar to the way that bind mounts work, except that volumes are managed by Docker.